# how to update order status in shopping cart to checkout

Tags: commerce

Here is my code for updating order status in shopping cart to Checkout: Checkout. After running no error but it does not show order status as Checkout: Checkout.

```
function commerce_services_order_checkout_update($order_id,$data, $flatten_fields) {
    $status; $message;

    $status = $data['status'];


    $order = commerce_order_load($order_id);
    $order = commerce_order_status_update($order, "Checkout: Checkout");
    if($order != null){
        $status = 1;
        $message = "Order status set to checkout successfully.";
    }else{
        $status = 0;
        $message = "Order status can not set to checkout.";
    }

   $reply= (array('status' => $status,'message' => $message, "order status ". $order));


    return $reply;
}
```

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem:

```
$order = commerce_order_status_update($order, "Checkout: Checkout");
```

You should be passing the machine name for the status

```
$order = commerce_order_status_update($order, 'checkout_checkout');
```

See this API doc page on drupalcontrib.org: http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!order!commerce_order.module/function/commerce_order_status_update/7

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order status using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

1. Event -> Choose after adding products to the cart
2. Action -> Update the status